# Sub-attributes of a product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, attribute-set

Is it possible to create a sub-attribute of an attribute?

Our website has started getting very complicated because it has thousands of products within many categories.

We've decided to start fresh with a brand new Magento installation and we're going to start making use of filters based on attributes to make the user experience much easier. How would we go about creating product attributes within attributes, for example:

We've got an attribute called `manufacturer` and within this we need `model` attributes:

`iPhone` - `4`, `4S`, `5`, `5C`, `6`, `6S`

You may be able to purchase a charger (for example) that fits both the iPhone 4 and the iPhone 4S, so when going to the "Chargers" category, there needs to be an option of "Apple, Samsung etc" and when clicking the "Apple" manufacturer, you'll have sub-attributes named "4, 4S" available to click.

Sorry if this makes no sense - I'm struggling to get my head around it myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make sub-attributes.

Want you want to do is create two attributes

`manufacturer`
`model`

You the set the attribute to "filterable with results".
If you don't want to show the model attribute without previous selection of an manufacturer, that is something you can achieve with various Layered Navigations Extensions.

Comment: The only problem with this is that every model will be visible despite the manufacturer choice. For example, `iPhone Galaxy S6` - haha! Not to worry, I've found some pretty decent (but expensive) plugins that will do the trick (should writing our own fail!).

Comment: I strongly recommend somethign like "SEO Layered Navigation" without naming the manufacturer but recommending to google ;)